# Rotating touch driver in kernel

Tags: linux-device-driver, hid, android-kernel

I have this Xenarc 7" touch screen with an eGalaxy controller, USB 0eef:0001.  The problem is that the X-Y orientation of the display is 90 degrees off from the touch controller.  In Xorg I would fix this with calibration, but I'm trying to do something in android 11, so I need to take a different approach.

Basically, the fix is:

y <- x
x <- 4096 - y

I'm trying to track down where to do this.  There is a quirk that match this vendor:device:

```
hid-quirks.c:   { HID_USB_DEVICE(USB_VENDOR_ID_DWAV, USB_DEVICE_ID_EGALAX_TOUCHCONTROLLER), HID_QUIRK_MULTI_INPUT | HID_QUIRK_NOGET },
```

which I thought would mean it would use hid-multitouch.c as the specific hid driver, but I put debug messages in  mt_touch_input_mapping() which is where I thought I would do the transformation.  What I found is that function never gets called.

```
[    3.319231] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0eef, idProduct=0001, bcdDevice= 1.00
[    3.327836] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    3.335421] usb 1-1.1: Product: USB TouchController
[    3.340555] usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: eGalax Inc.
[    3.350584] Found special quirk 0x48 for HID device 0x0eef:0x0001
```

but I think I see evidence that it is being driven by only hid-generic:

```
[    3.411400] hid-generic 0003:0EEF:0001.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v2.10 Pointer [eGalax Inc. USB TouchController] on usb-0000:01:00.0-1.1/input0
```

and there's no code in hid-generic to deal specifically with touch screens.

getevent does see events from touches:

```
/dev/input/event1: EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000
/dev/input/event1: EV_ABS       ABS_X                000007b5
/dev/input/event1: EV_ABS       ABS_Y                000006ba
```

I'm left trying to figure out how this works, and wondering if it's not being used as a multitouch device at all but, rather, it's just sending EV_ABS events.  Net, I looked in drivers/hid to see what sends those, and the only thing I can find is wacom_wac.c.  I do not think that's being used here because there's no mention of it in dmesg or /sys.

So I'm left wondering what's processing these device events and sending them on to the input subsystem, and, probably more to the point, where can I intercept them (in the kernel) so that I can do my affine transformation magic on x and y ?  Is it actually all handled by hid-input.c ?  It seems like me adding the rotation as a quirk would be an awful thing to do in such a generic place, and that I need to figure out how to force it to use hid-multitouch or maybe something new.

Comment: I see a set of quirks for this device `drivers/hid/hid-quirks.c:77:    { HID_USB_DEVICE(USB_VENDOR_ID_DWAV, USB_DEVICE_ID_EGALAX_TOUCHCONTROLLER), HID_QUIRK_MULTI_INPUT | HID_QUIRK_NOGET },` https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/hid/hid-quirks.c#L77

Comment: And yes, it seems it's being served by generic USB HID -> HID drivers.

Comment: I saw that, too (it was in my quesiton).  So do I need to make it use its own driver?  I'm not sure if I would do that by setting HID_QUIRK_HAVE_SPECIAL_DRIVER, or just adding the VID:PID to hid-multitouch (or a new driver).

Comment: Does it acutally use hid-generic.c AND hid-input.c ?